Gatling (Java) Junit Report
I am running Gatling with Java in one of my projects and just came across the question whether it is possible to get a JUnit XML report out of my defined assertions. Some actually fail and some succeed. It would be nice to have that in machine readable files, rather than just the console log and/or html report.
I was not able to details on this.

Have you tried  https://github.com/Pravoru/gatling-junitrunner ?

i have not, because last commit was 6 years ago. Is it still working?
